# Django/HTML Templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I purchased a bootstrap template that references assets files via a scripts.js file like so:

ref in scripts file:
loadScript(plugin_path + 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', function() {

ref in html index file:
script type="text/javascript">var plugin_path = 'assets/plugins/';

I've been trying to reference this to my static files like so without any luck.

script type="text/javascript">var plugin_path = "{% static
 'assets/plugins' %}";

Left the closures off so it would show here properly in my question. Any suggestions on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: perhaps you forgot to `{% load staticfiles %}` have you checked the generated HTML to see if the template tag is being transformed to HTML?

Comment: yes do have the load {% load staticfiles %}, I'm using Amazon S3 for static files, ive got no issue anywhere else on static files just the reference  var plugin_path = "{% static 'assets/plugins' %}"; seems to be what is having the issue